# Function mimicing Excel MMULT

Tags: vba, excel

I wanted to create function that mimics standard Excel MMULT function for multiplying matrices. My code is:

```html
Function MatrixMultiplication(Matrix1 As Range, Matrix2 As Range)

Dim m1() As Long, m2() As Long, m3() As Long
m1 = Matrix1
m2 = Matrix2

If Matrix1 Is Nothing Or Matrix2 Is Nothing Then GoTo Err1
If UBound(m1, 2) <> UBound(m2, 1) Then GoTo Err2

ReDim m3(UBound(m1, 1), UBound(m2, 2))

For i = LBound(m1) To UBound(m1, 1)
    For j = LBound(m2) To UBound(m1, 2)
        For k = 1 To UBound(m1, 2)
        m3(i, j) = m3(i,j)+ m1(i, k) * m2(k, i)
        Next k
    Next j
Next i

Dim Matrix3 As Range

Set Matrix3 = Range(ActiveCell.Address, ActiveCell.Offset(UBound(m1, 1) - 1, UBound(m2, 2) - 1))

Matrix3 = m3

Set MatrixMultiplication = Matrix3

Err1:
    Selection.Cells(0, 0).Value = CVErr(xlErrNull)
Err2:
    Selection.Cells(0, 0).Value = CVErr(xlErrNA)

End Function
```

Somehow it does not work. It should work as CSE function. Thanks for any help.

Comment: It makes more sense to write a function which takes two variants and returns a variant. Why are you trying to return a range rather than a variant?

Comment: But if I return variant, will it work the same as MMULT? I mean as CSE formula?

Comment: Yes -- it will. If a variant (containing an array) is returned then that array can be returned as the value of a UDF used as an array formula

Comment: I tried changing to variant and still get #Arg...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a version that works. A somewhat subtle point is that if you pass it arrays which are given in ranges then you need to convert them to regular arrays. Note the two lines near the beginning of the function that do that:

```
Function MatrixProduct(A As Variant, B As Variant) As Variant
    'Assumes that A,B are 1-based variant arrays
    'Or ranges containing such things.
    'Little error checking is done

    Dim m As Long, n As Long, p As Long, i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
    Dim C As Variant

    If TypeName(A) = "Range" Then A = A.Value
    If TypeName(B) = "Range" Then B = B.Value
    m = UBound(A, 1)
    p = UBound(A, 2)
    If UBound(B, 1) <> p Then
        MatrixProduct = "Not Defined!"
        Exit Function
    End If
    n = UBound(B, 2)

    ReDim C(1 To m, 1 To n)
    For i = 1 To m
        For j = 1 To n
            For k = 1 To p
                C(i, j) = C(i, j) + A(i, k) * B(k, j)
            Next k
        Next j
    Next i
    MatrixProduct = C
End Function
```

This can be used directly in the spreadsheet and also be used directly in VBA code. It is almost definitely slower then the built-in MMULT, so I'm not quite sure how useful it is.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's only for self-learning purposes. I know it must be slwoer than MMULT